# Understanding the difference between numpy.log and numpy.sum for custom array containers

Tags: python, numpy

I am creating a custom container for a NumPy array by following [the instructions on the SciPy website](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.dispatch.html). I've written the following code which:

- creates a class, `NpContainer`
- defines custom behavior for the functions `np.sum` and `np.log` to output a string.

```py
import numpy as np

HANDLED_FUNCTIONS = {}

class NpContainer:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __array__(self):
        return np.array(self.val)

    def __array_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs):
        if func not in HANDLED_FUNCTIONS:
            raise NotImplementedError()

        return HANDLED_FUNCTIONS[func](*args, **kwargs)

def implements(np_function):
    def decorator(func):
        HANDLED_FUNCTIONS[np_function] = func
        return func
    return decorator

@implements(np.sum)
def sum(a, **kwargs):
    return 'Sum Val: {}'.format(np.sum(a.val, **kwargs))

@implements(np.log)
def log(a, **kwargs):
    return 'Log Val: {}'.format(np.log(a, **kwargs))
```

I test the code using:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    container1 = NpContainer(val=np.array([1., 2.]))

    sum_result = np.sum(container1)
    print(sum_result)
    print(type(sum_result))

    log_result = np.log(container1)
    print(log_result)
    print(type(log_result))
```

Sum produces the expected result.

```
Sum Val: 3.0
<class 'str'>
```

However `np.log` returns a NumPy array instead of a string.

```
[0.         0.69314718]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Does anyone know why `np.log` skips my custom-defined function? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What would you expect to see returned instead? I mean ```sum``` sums all elements, ```log``` takes log from all elements?

Comment: I would like it to return ``Log Val: [0.         0.69314718]``. It seems to ignore my custom-defined log function (see ``@implements(np.log)``)

Comment: `np.log` is a `ufunc` (like `np.add` and `np.multiply`).  You need to define `__array_ufunc__`.

Comment: Thanks! You and @GrzegorzSkibinski hit the nail on the head!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I think - I know what is happening. You implemented function `__array_function__`, which should fit `np.sum` but for `np.log` you should do `__array_ufunc__`, since it is an universal function ([https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html#numpy.class.**array_ufunc**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html#numpy.class.__array_ufunc__)).

There's some more flavour to it, which I recommend you to check out here:

https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0018-array-function-protocol.html

Now oddly enough- once `__array_ufunc__` is implemented, even `np.sum` will be processed as `ufunc`, which messes up with the `decorator`.

`ufunc` auto-casted function for `np.sum` is `np.add`, so the below will do the trick for you - **although I would rather recommend to implement `sum()` as a function for `NpContainer` - so you can do `container1.sum()` instead**

```py
import numpy as np

HANDLED_FUNCTIONS = {}

class NpContainer:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __array__(self):
        return np.array(self.val)

    def __array_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs):
        if func not in HANDLED_FUNCTIONS:
            raise NotImplementedError()

        return HANDLED_FUNCTIONS[func](*args, **kwargs)

    def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *args, **kwargs):
        if ufunc not in HANDLED_FUNCTIONS:
            raise NotImplementedError()

        return HANDLED_FUNCTIONS[ufunc](*args, **kwargs)        

def implements(np_function):
    def decorator(func):
        HANDLED_FUNCTIONS[np_function] = func
        return func
    return decorator

@implements(np.add)
def sum(a, **kwargs):
    return 'Sum Val: {}'.format(np.sum(a.val, **kwargs))

@implements(np.log)
def log(a, **kwargs):
    return 'Log Val: {}'.format(np.log(a.val, **kwargs))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    container1 = NpContainer(val=np.array([1., 2.]))

    log_result = np.log(container1)
    print(log_result)
    print(type(log_result))

    sum_result = np.sum(container1)
    print(sum_result)
    print(type(sum_result))
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the detailed response. This is perfect and I'd definitely agree with your advice to implement ``container1.sum()``, especially after reading the warning about ``__array_function__`` from your second link.